# Create if an entry if it doesn't exist, otherwise update?

Tags: mysql

Kinda strange to put it into words that short, heh.

Anyway, what I want is basically to update an entry in a table if it does exist, otherwise to create a new one filling it with the same data.

I know that's easy, but I'm relatively new to MySQL in terms of how much I've used it :P

Comment: [Insert into a MySQL table or update if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4205181/6521116) or [MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY - last insert id?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/778534/6521116)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use 'REPLACE INTO':

```
 REPLACE INTO table SET id = 42, foo = 'bar';
```

See more in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)

Comment: It created more than on entry for REPLACE INTO user SET ip = '$uip', lastcheck = '$tim'

Comment: Then the behavior you are experiencing is expected. One field must either be primary or unique for this to work. Otherwise, how would MySQL know to prevent duplicates? 

It seems like you should have the user_id in this table (as a primary key) which you also set in your replace into.

Comment: So I have a primary key called uid that's INT, but it's still creating duplicates. Are you saying I need to modify the query? If so what should it end up as?

Comment: Actually, nevermind, I got it to work by changing ip into VARCHAR and setting that as UNIQUE.

Answer (score 84):

A lot of developers still execute a query to check if a field is present in a table and then execute an insert or update query according to the result of the first query.
Try using the ON DUPLICATE KEY syntax, this is a lot faster and better then executing 2 queries. More info can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

> INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (4,5,6)
>     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=9;

if you want to keep the same value for c you can do an update with the same value

> INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (4,5,6)
>     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=6;

the difference between 'replace' and 'on duplicate key':

> replace: inserts, or deletes and inserts
>
> on duplicate key: inserts or updates

if your table doesn't have a primary key or unique key, the replace doesn't make any sense.

You can also use the `VALUES` function to avoid having to specify the actual values twice. E.g. instead of

`INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (4,5,6) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=6;`

you can use

`INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (4,5,6) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(c);`

Where `VALUES(c)` will evaluate to the value specified prevously (6).

Comment: IMO, this response better answers the question. If you really want an UPDATE when the row already exists, REPLACE is destructive: "REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted." (MySQL manual)

Comment: Note that it's not exactly "Insert or Update" but "Insert or Delete+Insert" which means that this is not a proper solution if you meant to Update only a part of the Columns : Unlike an Update, the value of columns with no specified values will be set to Default value (and will be lost)

Comment: There a difference between 'REPLACE INTO' and 'INSERT INTO ... ONDUPLICATE KEY'. In the second one, you can access the old values (and even manipulate them like value = value + 1) and then avoid the old value being lost by including value = value in ON DUPLICATE to avoid value being set back to default

Answer (score 9):

As the others have said, `REPLACE` is the way to go. Just be careful using it though, since it actually does a `DELETE` and `INSERT` on the table. This is fine most of the time, but if you have foreign keys with constraints like `ON DELETE CASCADE`, it can cause some big problems.

Answer (score 3):

Look up [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) in the MySQL manual.

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT,
>   except that if an old row in the table
>   has the same value as a new row for a
>   PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old
>   row is deleted before the new row is
>   inserted. See Section 12.2.5, “INSERT
>   Syntax”.
>
> REPLACE is a MySQL extension to the
>   SQL standard. It either inserts, or
>   deletes and inserts. For another MySQL
>   extension to standard SQL — that
>   either inserts or updates — see
>   [Section 12.2.5.3](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), “INSERT ... ON
>   DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax”.

If you have the following INSERT query:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, field1, field2) VALUES (1, 23, 24)
```

This is the REPLACE query you should run:

```
REPLACE INTO table (id, field1, field2) VALUES (1, 23, 24)
```