# Getting last insert id for mysql after Insert

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a query like so:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (field1,field2) VALUES ('$value1','$value2') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field1 = '$value1'
```

I then want to get the last insert id if it does the insert, how can I do this? If the query ends up doing an update I dont want the last insert id. Is there a way to determine if it did an update or a insert?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY - last insert id?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778534/mysql-on-duplicate-key-last-insert-id)

Comment: possible duplicate of ["INSERT IGNORE" vs "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I should of searched the site before posting. Basically adding this worked:

```
id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)
```

On the on duplicate update. I found that answer here:

[Duplicate Key Last Insert ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778534/mysql-on-duplicate-key-last-insert-id)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this MySQL Manual Page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

> If a table contains an AUTO_INCREMENT
>   column and INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY
>   UPDATE inserts or updates a row, the
>   `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function returns the
>   AUTO_INCREMENT value.