# How to get ID row of updated row?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my query:

```
INSERT INTO table (value) VALUES (value) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value=value
```

With `mysql_insert_id()` I get the new inserted ID, but how to get the ID of row updated?

I tried `mysql_insert_id()` but, for updated row, I get 0.

Comment: i dont think its possible in mysql

Comment: Wanting to see what answers are posted. Have had the same issue in the past. I always just did select after.

Answer (score 2):

[MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY - last insert id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778534/mysql-on-duplicate-key-last-insert-id)

"Check this page out: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html
At the bottom of the page they explain how you can make LAST_INSERT_ID meaningful for updates by passing an expression to that MySQL function."

Comment: Last updated ID of the row updated in query "ON DUPLICATE KEY update..."

Comment: @Leonardo the last example on that page shows you how to do that

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do that. You could do SELECT id FROM table WHERE value = value;

Answer (score 0):

Well since you already have a `WHERE` statement you can select it with a different query. `mysql_insert_id()` does exactly what it says. Get an ID from an INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with MySQL 5.1.12, [it's possible](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-insert-id.html).  MySQL's last_insert_id function will return the value of the autoincrement field for both insert and update operations.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get the insert id with the mysql_insert_id() php function.

However when combined with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, you'll have to do a bit more if you want mysql_insert_id() to give you the key that was updated, instead of the new key generated that was inserted.

Change your SQL to

```
INSERT INTO table (value) VALUES (value) 
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id),value=value;
```

See more info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)