# How to get the PK of a ignored row in an INSERT IGNORE statement

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I have an `INSERT` statement with an `IGNORE` option, because I have a unique field in the insert statement, that is not the primary key. I am using the `getGeneratedKeys()` command on a `PreparedStatement` object to get the keys of newly generated rows. Is it possible to configure JDBC in a way so that it returns the id of the ignored row in the case of a query where the `IGNORE` triggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer [mysql - after insert ignore get primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291405/mysql-after-insert-ignore-get-primary-key) seems to indicate that a multi-step workaround is required to retrieve the details of the ignored rows.

With the optional alternative of using `REPLACE INTO` if you can afford the additional overhead of replacing the rows rather than ignoring them.