# Can INSERT IGNORE return added values?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I have simple query in PHP code. It adds specific values to database only if something doesn't exist:

```
$query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO images (filename) VALUES ('test2'),('dat7'), ... ";
if (!mysql_query($query)) print mysql_error();
```

Database structure:

```
"id" (Primary and AUTO_INCREMENT) | "filename" (unique)
```

And now is my question. Is it possible to get information in return, from database, about list of "id" values added during this query? I don't need information about "filename" values added, only list of newly created "id" during last query.

Comment: try using http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php to get the last inserted id

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql - after insert ignore get primary key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291405/mysql-after-insert-ignore-get-primary-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it with the use of mysql_insert_id() function after each insert query execution. keep an array of these ids and make use of it.