# Python, Flask, MySQL - Check if email exists in database

Tags: python, mysql, sql, flask

I'm pretty new to SQL but I need it for a school project. I'm trying to make a (python) web-app which requires accounts. I'm able to put data into my SQL database but now I need some way to verify if an e-mail (inputted via html form)  already exists inside the database. Probably the easiest query ever but I haven't got a single clue on how to get started. :(

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate question but I can't find anything out there that does what I need.

Comment: What is the columns in your DB table?

Comment: - Database name: essentials
- Table name: users
- column name: email

Comment: Can you write the code you already have? (reading the email from the user, querying the DB?)

Comment: I don't have any python code reading the data although a SQL query reading the emails would look like this
`SELECT email FROM essentials.users;`

Comment: If you have troubles with SQL specifically, then consider using WHERE clause (in conjunction with IF EXISTS clause, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue by simply using
`INSERT IGNORE` and after that [checking if it was ignored with the primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26801227/python-mysqldb-mysql-insert-ignore-checking-if-ignored).

Thank you for everyone that helped out though!

Answer (score 1):

if you are using SQLAlchemy in your project:

```
@app.route("/check_email")
def check_email():
    # get email from you form data
    email = request.form.get("email")

    # check if someone already register with the email
    user = Users.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    if not user:
        # the email doesnt exist
        pass
    else:
        # the email exists
        pass
```

`Users.query.filter_by(email=email).first()` equal to SQL:

```
SELECT * from users where email="EMAIL_FROM_FORM_DATA"
```

if you are using `pymsql`(or something like that):

```
import pymsql

@app.route("/check_email")
def check_email():
    # get email from you form data
    email = request.form.get("email")

    conn = connect(host='localhost',port=3306,user='',password='',database='essentials')
    cs1 = conn.cursor()
    params = [email]
    # cursor return affected rows
    count = cs1.execute('select * from users where email=%s', params)  # prevent SqlInject

    if count == 0:
        # count 0 email
    else:
        # the email exists
        # and if you want to fetch the user's info
        user_info = cs1.fetchall()  # the user_info should be a tuple


    # close the connection
    cs1.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Using your 'style of attack' ;) outputs none as count. No matter what the email is.

Comment: Are you using `pymysql`? or other mysql client? there may be difference among these. by the way,  the the first line should be `from pymysql import connect`.

Comment: I use the `mysql-connector` but I got it to work using a simple INSERT IGNORE`