# INSERT and return ID, or if DUPLICATE KEY return existing ID in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a "tags" table, which has a UNIQUE on the "tags" column, to prevent duplicates.

I have a "bookmarks_tags" table, which relates bookmarks to tags, and it has a UNIQUE on the "bookmark_id" and "tag_id" columns, to prevent duplicates.

However, I need people to be able to add the same tag, and to accomplish this, I need some means of retrieving the ID of the existing tag to use as reference in the "bookmarks_tags" table.

Is there a way of writing an INSERT so that if it detects a duplicate, it returns the ID of that duplicate? Or, alternatively, would an INSERT ... SELECT be more appropriate for "bookmarks_tags" table?

The key thing here is that it has to work under both conditions; add as new, or retrieve old.

Also, LAST_INSERT_ID() is useless in this scenario, as the tag in question could have been added at any time.

Any ideas?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table) will help you

Comment: I can write a SELECT query, but that isn't the problem. I need to know if an INSERT can accomplish the same thing, saving the extra coding; I'm using a framework, so there's several files that would need changing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY - last insert id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778534/mysql-on-duplicate-key-last-insert-id)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this is using `INSERT IGNORE`:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tags (tags,...) VALUES (the_new_tags, ...);

SELECT tag_id FROM tags WHERE tags=the_new_tags;
```

Comment: Okay, that's the way I'm going. It's the one with the least hassle. Ross, thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't @Pham Duc Quang method be better? Only requires one query.

Comment: Yes, `INSERT INTO tags SET tags=the_new_tags ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tag_id=LAST_INSERT_ID(tag_id)` should work better, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: `Insert IGNORE` is a *bad idea* since it will ignore all errors (type, length etc.), instead is `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE key=key` but will correctly throw other errors. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html
See other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16796885/3343553

Answer (score 23):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table SET unique1=value1 AND unique2=value2… ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)";
$insert_result = mysql_query($query);
$id = mysql_insert_id();
return $id;
```

[Insert Into Database or Return ID of Duplicate Row in MySQL](http://mikefenwick.com/blog/insert-into-database-or-return-id-of-duplicate-row-in-mysql/) (Backup link [@WebArchive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150925012041/http://mikefenwick.com:80/blog/insert-into-database-or-return-id-of-duplicate-row-in-mysql/))

Comment: Is there a way to distinguish a new and a duplicate returned id?

Comment: Broken link. :(

Comment: @JaredDunham backup link added ;-)

Comment: Do note this will cause autoincrements to increment