# Get id value of last inserted record(s) in openerp

Tags: odoo

I need to retrieve every id of last inserted records inside the account.analytic.line so that  can insert the value of that id into line_id in hr_analytic_timesheet in order to show the record inserted in account.analytic.line to table in hr_analytic_timesheet . Here's my code :

```
project_obj = self.pool.get('notebook.project').search(cr, uid, [('project_id','=', project_sheet)])
        for p in self.pool.get('notebook.project').browse(cr, uid, project_obj):
            cr.execute('insert into account_analytic_line (account_id,user_id,unit_amount,amount,product_id,product_uom_id,general_account_id,journal_id,name,date,to_invoice) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) returning last_insert_id of account_analytic_line into hr_analytic_timesheet (line_id) where last_insert_id = %s', (p.account_id,p.user_code,p.unit_amount,p.amount,p.product_id,p.product_uom_id,p.general_account_id,p.journal_id,p.desc,p.date,p.to_invoice))
        return res
```

I tried code above but it gives me error tuple index out of range .
I've searched in site , but only found solution for mySQL , so I'm not really sure how to apply the solutions such as [Duplicate Key Last Insert ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778534/mysql-on-duplicate-key-last-insert-id) . Please help !

Answer (score 1):

Don't use direct SQL to insert the record, instead use `create` method. it will return you the ID of record created.

Comment: okay then can you suggest me how to use create in order to add value to those record ?

Comment: you can refer to this documentation : https://doc.openerp.com/trunk/server/api_models/#openerp.osv.orm.BaseModel.create

Comment: let's say that i insist to use insert into , my only problem left is to get id generated from inserted records at account.analytic.line and insert it into field line_id inside hr.analytic.timesheet module . As simple as that . Is there any other way than using create method ?

Comment: As far as i know , the method create only allow value modification only for the field inside module that using create method itself , so method create can't modify other field inside other module ( ex. the create method is in my notebook.project while the value i want to modify is fields inside account.analytic.line .. Is that true ?

Comment: No, you can modify any record from another record and can create as well. To modify any values you have to use `write` method.

Comment: let's say that i still used insert into account.analytic.line for records , can i def create in hr analytic instead ?