# How to understand if MySQL updated or inserted

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This seems like such a simple problem but Google cannot seem to find much on the topic.

For caching reasons I want to run a query to let a user like something:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_review_vote (user_id,review_id,vote) VALUES(:uid,:rid,:vote) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE vote=:vote
```

But then understand from the server response whether or not the like was inserted or updated so that I can pre-aggregate a `likes` to the user review record.

Is there a good way of doing this?

Comment: Hi it is asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778534/mysql-on-duplicate-key-last-insert-id

Comment: You can look at the number of rows inserted. Which MySQL API are you using?

Comment: I don't know if you're using any DB class, but usually (even the simple `mysql_query()` does the same, for ex) the return values are different (true/resource), so you can check that. Look on the doc of the methods you're using

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky The number of rows does not work, that can represent inserted or updated

Comment: @DamienPirsy I am using PDO and any return is not disconcernable between insert and update that I can see

Comment: @SerhatAkay that linked answer didn't help but Shamils did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row and 2 if an existing row is updated. You could then look at the difference between mysql's `LAST_INSERT_ID()` and your API's last_insert_id to ascertain whether it was an insert or an update.

An alternative way to see what it was, is by adding an `update_count` column which increments with your query:  `update_count = update_count + ;`, or alternatively, a `timestamp` without `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 0):

Try these php functions:

mysql_affected_rows()
or
mysqli_affected_rows()

Comment: This is not an answer, also the question clearly states PDO is being used, not mysqli.