# MySQL INSERT with ON DUPLICATE SELECT possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, last-insert-id

```
email_address
-------------
id
prefix
fqdn
```

Prefix and fqdn together form a unique key.

I would like to write a query which would do an insert, if the email address is not yet in the table.  If the address is already in the table, it should return the id.

Is there a way of writing a query which behaves like `INSERT INTO email_address(prefix, fqdn) VALUES (?, ?) ON DUPLICATE SELECT id as LAST_INSERT_ID WHERE prefix = ? AND fqdn = ?` would if it were legal?

Basically I want to do an INSERT *or* SELECT in one query.

Comment: No, this is not possible in MySQL, to my knowledge. However, you could do so in your application code (PHP, etc.) without too much trouble.

Comment: If `prefix` and `fqdn` form 1 unique (primary) key, why do you think you need `id` column ? Removing `id` resolves your whole non-sense workarround and tryhard selecting something you already have.

Comment: What is "SELECT __or__ INSERT"? What sense that can have?

Comment: I agree with @TimBurch - I'd probably handle this by _default_ in the application layer; since `id` is usually best incremented by the DB, you have to `SELECT` after insertion to get it anyways...  Attempt the insert, then on duplicate-key failure (or no-rows-affected, if the insert is written that way) don't report the error (probably), just perform the selection the row, as if nothing happened.  Multiple questions here for this kind of design, though.

Comment: @DanFromGermany - Having a surrogate key allows things like changing email addresses associated with accounts (or much easier, anyways).  StackExchange probably uses this in the backend, given I've changed my email address associated with this account...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse this of course is true.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY - last insert id?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778534/mysql-on-duplicate-key-last-insert-id)

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Thanks, can you paste that into an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @AlmaDo It's either "`INSERT` the row and get the `LAST_INSERT_ID`" or "`SELECT` the id of the matching row".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a table contains an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column and `INSERT ... UPDATE`
>   inserts a row, the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function returns the
>   `AUTO_INCREMENT` value. If the statement updates a row instead,
>   `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is not meaningful. However, you can work around this
>   by using `LAST_INSERT_ID(expr)`. Suppose that id is the `AUTO_INCREMENT`
>   column. To make `LAST_INSERT_ID()` meaningful for updates, insert rows
>   as follows:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), c=3;
```

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: You still have to perform a `SELECT` after this (or call the C API function), of course, it just means you can use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` for it; given that he already has a unique key, there isn't much need.  It should be pointed out that, thankfully, the value of the supplied parameter for the function is connection-based, so is threadsafe.