# PHP's PDO prepared INSERT statement: am I able to define if the insert was successful?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert, insert-update

I have the following code:

```
$add_rq = $DBH->prepare('INSERT INTO `table` SET `url` = :url ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `url`=`url`');
if($add_rq->execute(['url' => $url]))
  echo "Added (id: ".$DBH->lastInsertId().")";
else
  echo "Not added";
```

If the inserting `url` already exist in the table the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement working but the return value of the `execute()` is always `TRUE`. However `lastInsertId()` is zero in this case. I COULD use this as the indication of the insertion duplication or I could do one more query to DB prior to the insert but both approaches looks bad to me.

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$add_rq->rowCount()`. According to a comment in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php#109891), it will return `1` if a new row was inserted, `2` if an existing row was updated. But apparently that's wrong, it returns `0` if a row was updated.

`execute()` only returns false if it fails because of an error.

Comment: Thanks! That worked fine for me. But in my case if the row already exist in the table the return value was `0` (not `2`). Could you make clear and edit your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Update the id if it is duplicate

Then `lastInsertId()` will return the id (instead of 0) after an update
It will return the id after an insert either way

```
INSERT INTO `table` SET `url` = :url ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `url`=`url`, id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)
```

now this will return the `id` even if no new rows were inserted

```
$DBH->lastInsertId()
```

To find out if there was an insert of update, you could add another column called "updated" with a default value of 0, then when it updates it should set the column to 1

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`url`) VALUES (?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `url`=?, `updated`=`updated`+1
```

Source: it's mentioned at the bottom of the mysql manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.htm
[MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY - last insert id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778534/mysql-on-duplicate-key-last-insert-id)

Comment: The main thing I wanted to achieve is not to find out which row I referred but is there was insert **or** update.

Comment: oh sorry, I misunderstood the question then, I edited the answer