# Get last ID of a newly inserted element, or of an existing one

Tags: mysql

I have a following map table, with a unique key on the name column:

```
id | name
1    aaa
2    bbb
3    ccc
```

I want to get a newly created ID if I insert a new value to this table, like this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO map VALUES(null, 'ddd');
```

I know I can do this with `getLastId()` function. But I also want to get ID if a name already exists, and `getLastId()` function returns 0 in such case:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO map VALUES(null, 'ccc');
```

Is this possible to do with one SQL, and without checking if a record exists, etc?

Comment: `getLastId()` won't give you the value of the "id" column even on insert either. The ID in your case is "name". And you have the "name" already. That's more a conceptual thing on what an *Identity* is actually I'd say.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to go the extra mile for that one:

- check if exists - when so: get ID of that name
- if not: `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what qualifies as a single query.

When you make use of `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` you can control the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in such a manner that it will return the new id on insert and the id of the row "updated" on update:

```
INSERT INTO map (name) VALUE ('ccc') 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id);
```

That will make the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` then return the `map.id` of the row you're interested in.

Whatever the API is that you name as the `getLastId()` (I don't know it so I can't provide more pointers on it) this may not work and you would then need to fire a second query to obtain it:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

See as well:

- [MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY - last insert id?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/778534/367456) (Stackoverflow Q&A, Apr 2009)