# How to get lastrowid from sqlalchemy after INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy to do an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` in MySQL, and I'm trying to find the [`lastrowid`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html?highlight=lastrowid#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy.lastrowid) of the primary key that was inserted or updated.

However, when the `DUPLICATE` clause is triggered, the returned [`lastrowid`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html?highlight=lastrowid#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy.lastrowid) is 0, when I expected it to be the primary key of the record that was just updated. 
Minimal code to reproduce -- assume for this example that the combination of `first_name`+`last_name` is the unique key:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
eng = create_engine(connection_string)
query = "INSERT INTO user (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('Jim', 'Brown') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE first_name='Jim' "
record_id = eng.execute(query).lastrowid
```

After this runs, if there is a duplicate, then `record_id` is 0 instead of the primary key value. I expect to see. How can I get the primary key of the updated row?

I've also tried [`inserted_primary_key`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy.inserted_primary_key), which throws the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Statement is not a compiled expression construct.
```

Comment: I assume the combination of `first_name`,`last_name` is the primary/unique key? So for duplicates/`record_id=0` it has to be looked up. Also names aren't unique, trust someone called Daniel Black to know :-)

Comment: Your construction is not valid. Perform SELECT with new values in WHERE and retrieve according `id`.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the output of `DESCRIBE user;`?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778534/mysql-on-duplicate-key-last-insert-id, the workaround for when `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is triggered based on unique key instead of the primary is to include `ID = LAST_INSERT_ID(ID)` in the UPDATE.

Answer (score 3):

The comments hint at this but figured I'd reference a good example that shows how to do `insert ... on duplicate key update` with `LAST_INSERT_ID` in `sqlalchemy` . Check out [this](https://gist.github.com/vanpelt/1568296c0d6c97a4472ce1fcde73fc6c) gist. Lifting the code here for reference but please give the author a star.

```py
from app import db
from sqlalchemy import func
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import insert

def upsert(model, insert_dict):
    """model can be a db.Model or a table(), insert_dict should contain a primary or unique key."""
    inserted = insert(model).values(**insert_dict)
    upserted = inserted.on_duplicate_key_update(
        id=func.LAST_INSERT_ID(model.id), **{k: inserted.inserted[k]
                               for k, v in insert_dict.items()})
    res = db.engine.execute(upserted)
    return res.lastrowid
```

Note that `inserted_primary_key` also works for me with this approach.