# Insert into a MySQL table or update if exists

Tags: mysql, sql, insert-update, upsert

I want to add a row to a database table, but if a row exists with the same unique key I want to update the row.

For example:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (ID, NAME, AGE) VALUES(1, "A", 19);
```

Let’s say the unique key is `ID`, and in my **Database**, there is a row with `ID = 1`. In that case, I want to update that row with these values. Normally this gives an error.
If I use `INSERT IGNORE` it will ignore the error, but it still won’t update.

Comment: SQL needs an official syntax for this use case that doesn't force duplication of values in the syntax and preserves the primary key.

Comment: To get the influenced id  refer to [MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY - last insert id?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/778534/6521116)

Comment: **Caveat:** as of version 5.7 this approach does not directly support WHERE clause as part of the INSERT/UPDATE operation. Also, an UPDATE actually counts as two separate operations (DELETE and INSERT) ... in case that matters for audit purposes. (Learnbit)

Answer (score 2089, accepted):

Use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

**QUERY:**

```
INSERT INTO table (id, name, age) VALUES(1, "A", 19) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    
name="A", age=19
```

Comment: +1 From what I've found, this method is less problematic for auto-increment keys and other unique key collisions than REPLACE INTO, and it is more efficient.

Comment: I know all of you allude to this, but I want to be explicit for others.  If the ID you insert is NOT the PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE, then this will not work.  This didn't initially work for me because my ID was not unique.

Comment: This is a bit late, but anyway: it is stated in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html]) that updates in `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` increase the affected rows by 2. It reports 0 if nothing is actually updated (same as the regular `UPDATE`).

Comment: Also note that you can use VALUES (name) to reference to the value you attempt to insert e.g. INSERT INTO table (id, name, age) VALUES(1, "A", 19) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=VALUES(name) , age=VALUES(age)

Comment: Unfortunately `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` causes the autoincrement to increment even on updates, making this pretty much unusable if you need to do hundreds or thousands of these queries per day, since then the autoincrement will steadily increase by x rows every time even if no new rows are being added.

Comment: Another useful tip when using this in MySQL/MariaDB is the `INSERT INTO table SET col = val` syntax, allows for copy and pasting between the 2 parts of the query. so the above would be: `INSERT INTO table SET id = 1, name = "A", age = 19) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = "A", age = 19`

Comment: For MySQL 8.0.20+ VALUES() is now deprecated and will be removed. Use aliases.
Check the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 334):

Check out [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/9.0/en/replace.html):

> `REPLACE` works exactly like `INSERT`, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a `PRIMARY KEY` or a `UNIQUE` index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

Example:

```
REPLACE INTO `tablename` (`id`, `name`, `age`) VALUES (1, "A", 19)
```

Comment: @Piontek Because this one is shorter and easier to understand and no-one explained why "insert on duplicate" is better.

Comment: it changes the IDs of the record and thus may destroy foreign references.

Comment: The other problem with REPLACE INTO is that you _must_ specify values for ALL fields...otherwise fields will get lost or replaced with default values.  REPLACE INTO essentially **deletes** the row if it exists, and inserts the new row.  In the example, if you did 'REPLACE INTO table (id, age) values (1, 19) then the name field would become null.

Comment: This is actually DELETE the entire row and perform new INSERT.

Comment: all the comments here are true but... this might be exactly what is needed sometimes

Comment: @IceFire "But sometimes" is a bad reason to use something as the general approach.

Answer (score 76):

When using batch insert use the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (id, name, age) VALUES (1, "A", 19), (2, "B", 17), (3, "C", 22)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    name = VALUES (name),
    ...
```

Comment: If `VALUES(name)` does not work, you can try `name = 'name_value',...;`

Comment: VALUES is now deprecated - you should use

insert into TABLE (Id, name, age) values (1, "A", 19), (2, "B", 20) as ins on duplicate key update name=ins.name, age=ins.age;

Comment: all the name will be updated to  same value

Answer (score 52):

Any of these solution will work regarding your question:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table (id, name, age) VALUES (1, "A", 19);
```

or

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (id, name, age) VALUES(1, "A", 19) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE NAME = "A", AGE = 19;
```

or

```
REPLACE INTO table (id, name, age) VALUES(1, "A", 19);
```

Comment: I downvoted because this doesn’t explain the differences between these solutions and the drawbacks (if any) of each one.

Comment: I don't believe the first version produces the same results as the others. As I understand it, "IGNORE" will simply cause the DB to treat the conflict as a warning instead of an error. It will not update the conflicting row. Further, as others have pointed out, REPLACE INTO is effectively a DELETE/INSERT whereas ON DUPLICATE KEY will update an existing row.

Answer (score 26):

Try this:

`INSERT INTO table (id,name,age) VALUES('1','Mohammad','21') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='Mohammad',age='21'`

Note:
Here if id is the primary key then after first insertion with `id='1'` every time attempt to insert `id='1'` will update name and age  and previous name age will change.

Comment: I want to work without using *id*. Have you tried without primary key?

Comment: @ersks see the question. user asked about when there is an unique key

Comment: I got that, but I am trying to solve my problem in which these only values are know. So, in such situation I wrote above comment hoping correct solution.

Answer (score 25):

Try this out:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, name, age) VALUES (1, 'A', 19) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = id + 1;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually i don't need to add the new values to another row with a new ID instead i want to replace the existing values of id = 1 with this values. (as i understand this increments the id and add the data)

Comment: I don't think he wants to increase the id by one on duplicates.

Comment: "transgress" is not the word you're looking for :) Unfortunately, now I've seen "transgress", I can no longer visualise the actual word..

Comment: Updating an ID like this might mess with its sequence or get an error if there is an existing id+1

Answer (score 22):

In case that you wanted to make a `non-primary` fields as criteria/condition for `ON DUPLICATE`, you can make a `UNIQUE INDEX` key on that table to trigger the `DUPLICATE`.

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`name`);
```

And in case you want to combine two fields to make it unique on the table, you can achieve this by adding more on the last parameter.

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`name`, `age`);
```

Note, just make sure to delete first all the data that has the same `name` and `age` value across the other rows.

```
DELETE table FROM table AS a, table AS b WHERE a.id < b.id 
AND a.name <=> b.name AND a.age <=> b.age;
```

After that, it should trigger the `ON DUPLICATE` event.

```
INSERT INTO table (id, name, age) VALUES(1, "A", 19) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    
name = VALUES(name), age = VALUES(age)
```

Comment: I have tried that, I am gettting an error that says "BLOB/TEXT column 'column_name' used in key specification without a key length"

Comment: @Natalia kindly create a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) so I can check

Comment: I will try, but basically, you can not make text type of a column unique in MySQL. I made it varchar.

Comment: "DELETE table FROM table AS a, table AS b WHERE a.id < b.id 
AND a.name <=> b.name AND a.age <=> b.age;" gives me error "Unknown table 'table' in MULTI DELETE"

Answer (score 17):

Just because I was here looking for this solution but for updating from another identically-structured table (in my case website test DB to live DB):

```
INSERT  live-db.table1
SELECT  *
FROM    test-db.table1 t
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        ColToUpdate1 = t.ColToUpdate1,
        ColToUpdate2 = t.ColToUpdate2,
        ...
```

As mentioned elsewhere, only the columns you want to update need to be included  after `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

No need to list the columns in the `INSERT` or `SELECT`, though I agree it's probably better practice.

Answer (score 16):

When using SQLite:

```
REPLACE into table (id, name, age) values(1, "A", 19)
```

Provided that `id` is the primary key. Or else it just inserts another row. See *[INSERT](https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)* (SQLite).

Comment: What `replace into` does is exactly "insert into, or update when existing". @Owl

Comment: +1 ( 1 of 3 ) I found this to work for my situation - I needed to replace an existing row with a unique key or if not there then add the row. Simplest of solutions here.

Comment: ( 2 of 3 ) My query: `CREATE TRIGGER worklog_update AFTER INSERT ON worklog
FOR EACH ROW
REPLACE INTO support_time_monthly_hours ( ProjectID, monthTotalTime, Year, Month ) SELECT jiraissue.PROJECT, SUM(worklog.timeworked), YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()), MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) FROM worklog, jiraissue WHERE worklog.issueid = jiraissue.ID AND jiraissue.PROJECT = (SELECT PROJECT FROM jiraissue WHERE NEW.issueid = jiraissue.ID ) AND worklog.startdate BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01 00:00:00') AND NOW();`

Comment: ( 3 of 3 ) Related question/answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41767517/insert-row-into-mysql-table-result-from-query-into-one-field-and-sql-function-re

Comment: The problem with this in mysql is that replace will remove other values in case they are not provided. However @fabiano-souza solution is more appropriate

Answer (score 6):

In case, you want to keep old field (For ex: name). The query will be:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, name, age) VALUES(1, "A", 19) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    
name=name, age=19;
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case i created below queries but in the first query if `id` 1 is already exists and age is already there, after that if you create first query without `age` than the value of `age` will be none

```
REPLACE into table SET `id` = 1, `name` = 'A', `age` = 19
```

for avoiding above issue create query like below

```
INSERT INTO table SET `id` = '1', `name` = 'A', `age` = 19 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id` = "1", `name` = "A",`age` = 19
```

may it will help you ...

Comment: Does anyone know why we must assign the values twice?  Why doesn't MySQL allow us to end the query at ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE without duplicating all the assignment statements? Some database tables have many columns, and this seems redundant / gratuitous.  I understand why we have the option for alternate assignments, but why not have the option to omit them as well?  Just curious if anyone knows.

Answer (score 5):

### Following are some of the possible approaches:

#### Using `INSERT INTO`

The [`INSERT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) statement allows you to insert one or more rows into a table

- First, specify the table name and a list of comma-separated columns inside parentheses after the `INSERT INTO` clause.
- Secondly, put a comma-separated list of values of the corresponding columns inside the parentheses following the `VALUES` keyword.

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name(column_name1, column_name2, column_name3) VALUES("col_value_1", "col_value_2", "col_value_3");
```

#### Using `INSERT INTO` with `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (column_name_1, column_name_2, column_name_3)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT "col_value_1", "col_value_2","col_value_3") AS tmp_name
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT column_name2 FROM table_name WHERE column_name = "sample_name"
) LIMIT 1;
```

#### Using `REPLACE INTO`

[`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html) works exactly like [`INSERT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html), except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

```sql
REPLACE INTO table_name(column_name1, column_name2, column_name3) VALUES("col_value_1", "col_value_2", "col_value_3");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better way to accomplish an INSERT and UPDATE without affecting the auto increment and on top of that getting back the primary key in either scenario in a consistent way. It does involve multiple commands but can be done on one line if desired. This would be in a case where one or more fields make up a unique constraint like in this case *country*.

If you want the primary key back from INSERT or UPDATE only null values

```
SET @now=NOW();
SET @country='Example Country',@country_code='EC',@country_overview='An example country overview.';
INSERT INTO country (country, country_code, country_overview, added_at, updated_at)
SELECT @country,@country_code,@country_overview, @now, @now
FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM country WHERE country=@country
);
SELECT countryid INTO @countryid FROM country WHERE country=@country;
UPDATE country 
SET 
country_code = @country_code, 
country_overview = @country_overview, 
updated_at = @now 
WHERE countryid = @countryid AND added_at <> @now;
```

If you want the primary key back from INSERT or UPDATE only null values

```
SET @now=NOW();
SET @country='Example Country',@country_code='EC',@country_overview='An example country overview.';
INSERT INTO country (country, country_code, country_overview, added_at, updated_at)
SELECT @country,@country_code, @now, @now
FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM country WHERE country=@country
);
SELECT countryid INTO @countryid FROM country WHERE country=@country;
UPDATE country 
SET 
country_code = COALESCE(country_code, @country_code), 
country_overview = COALESCE(country_overview, @country_overview), 
updated_at = @now 
WHERE countryid = @countryid AND added_at <> @now;
```

There are few other ways you can work with this to get the primary key back you could do the following as your last statement.

```
SELECT @countryid;
```