# Running a python with MySQL insert command getting an error on parameters

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to do an insert from **Python** to MySQL and I am getting

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement;
```

I have had a bit of a look online and I know its got something to do with `tuble` but I can't work out what to change, I have looked around and at my code, there are **10 items** in the `responce_data`, 10 in the SQL and I have 10 %s so I don't know where I am going wrong

```
 import urllib.parse
import requests
import mysql.connector


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="**",
  database="flightdata"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()


main_api = 'https://www.sydneyairport.com.au/_a/flights/?query=&flightType=departure&terminalType=domestic&date=2019-11-10&sortColumn=scheduled_time&ascending=true&showAll=true'

address = 'lhr'
url = main_api + urllib.parse.urlencode({address: address})

response_data = requests.get(url).json()
for element in response_data['flightData']:
    flight_id = element['id']
    airline = element['airline']
    destination = element['destinations']
    flightNumbers = element['flightNumbers']
    scheduledTime = element['scheduledTime']
    estimatedTime = element['estimatedTime']
    scheduledDate = element['scheduledDate']
    latestTime = element['latestTime']
    status = element['status']
    statusColor = element['statusColor']

    sql = "INSERT INTO flightinfo (id, airline, destinations, flightNumbers, scheduledTime, estimatedTime, scheduledDate, latestTime, status, statusColor) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"

    #sql = "INSERT INTO flightinfo (flight_id, airline, destination, flightNumbers, scheduledTime, estimatedTime, estimatedTime, scheduledDate, latestTime, status, statusColor ) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s ,%s))"
    val = [(flight_id, airline, " ".join(destination), ", ".join(flightNumbers), scheduledTime, estimatedTime,
            scheduledDate, latestTime, status, statusColor)]

mycursor.executemany(sql, val)

mydb.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "was inserted.")


print(airline, destination, flightNumbers, scheduledTime, "Estimated Time:" + " " + estimatedTime, "Scheduled Date:" + " " + scheduledDate, "Latest Time:" + " " + latestTime, "Status:" + " " +status, "Status Color:" + " " + statusColor)
```

Comment: You sql  is wrong it has `11 table columns` instead of `10` because of duplicate entry of `estimatedTime`

Comment: i took that our and i still have the same issue mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the trailing `,` in val and  change `val`  to be

```
val = [(flight_id, airline, destination, flightNumbers, scheduledTime, estimatedTime, scheduledDate, latestTime, status, statusColor)]
```

And don't forget to fix your **sql** to

```
sql = "INSERT INTO flightinfo (flight_id, airline, destination, flightNumbers, scheduledTime, estimatedTime, scheduledDate, latestTime, status, statusColor) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
```

**UPDATE:** 
And to avoid getting

> TypeError: Python 'list' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

You can convert the relevant fields to string for instance in your case you can do.

```
val = [(flight_id, airline, " ".join(destination), ", ".join(flightNumbers), scheduledTime, estimatedTime, scheduledDate, latestTime, status, statusColor)]
```

Comment: with new code i am getting   File "Sydneyimport.py", line 40, in <module>
    mycursor.executemany(sql, response_data)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 668, in executemany
    stmt = self._batch_insert(operation, seq_params)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 613, in _batch_insert
    raise errors.ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
 new code in question

Comment: check the update and don't forget to mark as best if solved your problem.

Comment: its kida worked but only inserted one row of data when there is around 500 for it to entered, changes in code https://codeshare.io/alWVLd so you can edit if you want

Comment: Thank you mate that worked thank so much , one last question , i need to rerun the code every 5 mins, is there a way to run the query to update all the data that is there and not delete it, i will do another one to delete all data after midnight

Comment: also mate i ran the code for today and i only fgot 3 records back and i should be seeing 300+ has that got something to do with 
address = '1hr'

Comment: For re-runing the code every five minutes check out **apscheduler**, and about updating or create check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696190/create-if-an-entry-doesnt-exist-otherwise-update

Comment: about the last question  I can't say coz I really don't know