# Insert into a MySQL table or update if exists on a non KEY field

Tags: python, mysql

I want to  INSERT INTO MySQL or UPDATE MySQL if exist without having to run 2 different queries.

I have checked
[Create if an entry if it doesn't exist, otherwise update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696190/create-if-an-entry-if-it-doesnt-exist-otherwise-update)

```
INSERT INTO table (a) VALUES (0)  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

but it only works if you check doubles on the key.
The issue is I want to check on another field that is not the key, but yet has so stay unique.
I want to ADD or UPDATE on checking the 'symbol' in my dictionary:

The data I get is (example)

```
forex = [{'symbol': 'EURUSD', 'price': '1.06763000'}, {'symbol': 'GBPEUR', 'price': '0.90339600'}, {'symbol': 'EURJPYC', 'price': '0.000011200'}]
```

The INSERT INTO I want to adapt is:

```
mycursor.executemany(f"INSERT INTO `param_forex` (Ticker,Price) 
                    VALUES ( %(symbol)s, %(price)s)", forex)
mydb.commit()
```

I do NOT want to use the REPLACE because of the auto increment field (REPLACE deletes and inserts)
The column I am checking for duplicates is `Ticker` in the table and symbol in the dictionary.

I am stuck. Is there a solution?

Comment: Why isn't there a unique index on this column if it has to stay unique?

Comment: If you can't use `ON DUPLICATE KEY` then you have to use multiple queries.

Comment: Its always best to at least give us a bit of a clue by showing us at least an example of the query. It stops us having to guess from a poorly described question what you actually mean.

Comment: Seems like a redesign of the database is what is really required here

Comment: Searching past answers, I found this same question has been asked many times over many years. Example from 2010: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180913/mysql-update-on-duplicate-key-without-a-unique-column Most of the answers are: _"add a unique constraint on the column you want to be unique, then use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`."_

Comment: The alternative is to run two queries, one to check if the row exists, then conditionally execute INSERT or UPDATE. Example from 2015: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495194/mysql-insert-on-duplicate-update-for-non-primary-key

Comment: *The issue is I want to check on another field that is not the key, but yet has so stay unique.* If the column must be unique then you must create according unique index. This is the only way to check the data consistency. *I do NOT want to use the REPLACE because of the auto increment field (REPLACE deletes and inserts)* REPLACE needs in unique constraint too.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I thought my question was pretty explanatory, and the accompagning query as well. I am only new so lacking some subtilities maybe. I don't think it deserved a -1 though...

Comment: I added a index on Ticke ans it does work. Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement, but as mentioned in the comments, you need to have a unique index on the 'Ticker' column. For example:

```
forex = [{'symbol': 'EURUSD', 'price': '1.06763000'}, {'symbol': 'GBPEUR', 'price': '0.90339600'}, {'symbol': 'EURJPYC', 'price': '0.000011200'}]

query = "INSERT INTO `param_forex` (Ticker, Price) VALUES (%(symbol)s, %(price)s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Price = VALUES(Price)"

mycursor.executemany(query, forex)
mydb.commit()
```

To make this work, just alter the table to include a unique key:

```
ALTER TABLE `param_forex` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `idx_Ticker` (`Ticker`);
```

Comment: I added a index on Ticke ans it does work. Thanks all